# Flutter asBroadcastStream duplicates data on change event

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, stream-builder

I have a provider class that provides a stream from Firestore data. I have two pages with StreamBuilders that use the data from this stream. This works well. The data is correct on both screens and I get no errors.

However, whenever the data changes in Firestore and the streams are updated I get duplicates in the stream data. After a second update I now have three of every item, etc.

Any idea why this is happening?

The Streambuilders:

```
// streambuilder 1 on page A
child: StreamBuilder(
  initialData: mediaProvider.currentState,
  stream: mediaProvider.getMedia(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<MediaItem> mediaList = snapshot.data;
    ...

// streambuilder 2 on page B
child: StreamBuilder(
  initialData: mediaProvider.currentState,
  stream: mediaProvider.getMedia(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<MediaItem> mediaList = snapshot.data;
    ...
```

The stream in the provider:

```
Stream<List<MediaItem>> getMedia() {
  Stream<List<MediaItem>> stream = _firestoreService
      .getMedia(
        albumId: _albumId,
        mediaFilter: _mediaFilter,
        uid: _authService.currentUser!.getId,
      )
      .asBroadcastStream();
  setCurrentState(stream);
  // controller.sink.add(stream);
  return stream;
}
```

And the stream in firestore_service.dart:

```
Stream<List<MediaItem>> getMedia({
  required String albumId,
  required MediaFilter mediaFilter,
  required String? uid,
}) async* {
  // no filter
  Stream mediaStream = _mediaCollectionReference
      .where('albumId', isEqualTo: albumId)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
  List<MediaItem> mediaList = [];
  await for (QuerySnapshot mediaSnapshot in mediaStream) {
    for (var mediaDoc in mediaSnapshot.docs) {
      MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromData(
          mediaDoc.id, mediaDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      mediaList.add(mediaItem);
    }
    yield mediaList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I did some more digging and I think I figured it out. In firestore_service.dart where I'm creating the stream I just needed to create a new empty list when looping over the snapshots. Otherwise the new updated data is added to the result list and therefore keeps growing on every change.

Here's what I changed:

```
Stream<List<MediaItem>> getMedia({
  required String albumId,
  required MediaFilter mediaFilter,
  required String? uid,
}) async* {
  // no filter
  Stream mediaStream = _mediaCollectionReference
      .where('albumId', isEqualTo: albumId)
      .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
  await for (QuerySnapshot mediaSnapshot in mediaStream) { // CHANGED THE ORDER
    List<MediaItem> mediaList = [];                        // OF THESE TWO LINES
    for (var mediaDoc in mediaSnapshot.docs) {
      MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromData(
          mediaDoc.id, mediaDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      mediaList.add(mediaItem);
    }
    yield mediaList;
  }
}
```